# Lifecycle rule not working using MinIO service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, minio

I am using MinIO service to manage the S3 bucket. And for some objets in S3, I want to set the Lifecycle policy. I have updated the following policy in MinIO using MinIO console

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
      {
            "Action": [
               "admin:SetTier",
               "admin:ListTier"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Sid": "EnableRemoteTierManagement"
      },
      {
            "Action": [
               "s3:PutLifecycleConfiguration",
               "s3:GetLifecycleConfiguration"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                        "arn:aws:s3:::*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Sid": "EnableLifecycleManagementRules"
      }
   ]
}
```

Then I tried to execute the Lifecycle configuration from the Spring-Boot application and using AWS S3 client, I simple try to execute the following line
`amazonS3Client.getBucketLifecycleConfiguration("testbucket");`

but I am getting the below error

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: A header you provided implies functionality that is not implemented (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 501; Error Code: NotImplemented;type here
```

Can anyone please suggest how to get and put lifecycle configuration using MinIO?

MinIO service configuration for Lifecycle management.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using Minio gateway which is deprecated. However, this is supported in current Minio version.You can read about migrate fs-gateway here https://min.io/docs/minio/kubernetes/upstream/operations/install-deploy-manage/migrate-fs-gateway.html